# Navigate inside a TabbedPage and keep the TabbedPage as Host

Tags: xamarin, navigation, tabbed

I'm trying to set tabs in my whole application.
I created a Tabbed page like this :

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:LogiStock.UI.Base.Views"
         x:Class="Views.TabbedPage1" >

<!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->


<views:HomePage x:Name="Test" Title="AA"/>
```

I can navigate on other page from my HomePage but when I do that, my TabbedPage go away.
How can I keep the navigation inside my tab ?
Im using Xamarin 4.4 and Prism 7.2

Comment: your home page needs to be wrapped in a `NavigationPage`, then you can navigate within that tab

Answer (score 0):

The only change you need to do is something like:

```
<NavigationPage Title="AA" IconImageSource="icon.png">
 <x:Arguments>
   <views:HomePage x:Name="Test" />
 </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage
```

And then you can push pages to this navigation stack :)